# Python Urllib game of guessing words

Tags: python, random, urllib

I've been struggling as I wanted to try the hanged man game on python : 
For those who don't know the game, you basically need to guess all the letters of a word (with a limited number of attempts previously announced).
What's difficult, is that I want each guessed letters to appear on the spare parts of the word to guess and the already used letters to be mentionned as well.
And as we've already decided the number of attempts allowed (let's say 10), I want to try to show the remaining attempts left !!

Here's what I've done already (the generate random words) but I'm stuck :

```
import urllib
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=1')
word =response.read().decode('utf-8').strip('[\"]')
print(word)
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Check the answer! @Alohomora

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine!

```py
import requests
from typing import List

def get_random_word() -> str:
    url:str = 'https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=1'
    response:requests.Response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        word = response.text.strip('[\"]')
        return word
    else:
        print("Impossible to connect!")

def open_letters_in_hidden_word(word:str, hidden_word:str, letter:str) -> str:
    hidden_word:List[str] = list(hidden_word)
    for index, word_letter in enumerate(word):
        if word_letter == letter:
            hidden_word[index] = word_letter
    hidden_word:str = ''.join(hidden_word)
    return hidden_word


def start_game():
    # Loading word from server
    word:str = get_random_word()

    attempts:int = 10

    hidden_word:str = '-' * len(word)

    while attempts:
        print(f"Attempts left: {attempts}")
        print(f"Word: {hidden_word}")

        letter:str = input("Enter letter: ")

        if letter in word:
            hidden_word:str = open_letters_in_hidden_word(word, hidden_word, letter)
        else:
            print("Failed attempt!")
            attempts -= 1

        if not attempts:
            print(f"You lose! Word: {word}") 
            return
        if word == hidden_word:
            print(f"You won! Word: {word}")
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_game()
```

Comment: @Alohomora Please accept this answer if it helped you!